# Having mod_rewrite not rewrite requests for a particular directory

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many forward rules written in my `.htaccess` file. However, for the requests to a certain directory and its subdirectory, say `wordpress`, I don't want to use the forward rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wordpress
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ...
RewriteRule ...
RewriteRule ...
RewriteRule ...
```

Of course, this does not work. How should I modify the second line?

Comment: Why "Of course, this does not work"? I see nothing wrong here (unless there is mistake in folder name (missing/extra symbol or wrong case).

Answer (score 2):

This should work for a single directory (for example your wordpress directory)...

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress/.$  -  [PT]
```

If you want mod_rewrite to ignore all directories, try something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

The RewriteCond is true if the path is a directory, and the Rule will stop rewrite processing. Just be sure to put this at the beginning of your ruleset.

Comment: Your first example is a bit wrong (I'm refering to the second `^` character -- must be just typo). Something like this will be enough (could add `NC` flag as well if case-insensitivity is required) `RewriteRule ^wordpress/ - [L]`

Comment: The first example is still wrong, the `.$` matches just a single character before the end of the URL (after `wordpress/`) so probably won't match anything. Best to omit this entirely, as in LazyOne's comment.

Answer (score 1):

As LazyOne notes, your example *should* work, more or less.  (That is, it might match some URLs you didn't intend to match, but it should indeed stop  any URLs containing `wordpress` from being rewritten.)  The way I'd recommend writing it is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^wordpress/ - [L]

# other rewrite rules here...
```

This will prevent any URL paths beginning with `wordpress/` from being rewritten.  If you also want to prevent rewriting for `http://www.yoursite.com/wordpress` without the trailing slash, you can either add a separate rule for it:

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress$ - [L]
```

or just replace the trailing `/` in the first rule above with `(/|$)`.